# Segmentation Failure with print and write instructions, in Implementation between Fortran and C

Tags: c, fortran

I'm trying to call a C function from Fortran, using the iso_c_binding interoperability. However, I am getting a SegFault error when trying to use print and write statements. Without the print and write statements the code works fine, but I need these statements to create an output file with the simulation data. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Note: I am using Ubuntu 20.04, GFortran, and GCC to compile the respective source codes.

```sh
gcc -c subroutine_in_c.c
```

```sh
gfortran -o exec main.f90 subroutine_in_c.o -lwiringPi
```

---

main.f90:

```
PROGRAM main
   USE, INTRINSIC:: iso_c_binding, ONLY: C_FLOAT

   IMPLICIT NONE

   REAL(KIND = 4) :: leitura_sensor = 0.0

   INTERFACE 
     SUBROUTINE ler_sensores(s1) BIND(C)
        USE, INTRINSIC :: iso_c_binding, ONLY: C_FLOAT
        IMPLICIT NONE
        REAL(KIND=C_FLOAT) :: s1
      END SUBROUTINE ler_sensores
   END INTERFACE

   !print*, 'Call subroutine in C language'

   call ler_sensores(leitura_sensor)

   !print*, 'Return to main.f90'

   OPEN(UNIT=1, FILE='output.txt', STATUS='unknown')

   WRITE(1,*) leitura_sensor

   CLOSE(UNIT=1)

END PROGRAM main
```

---

subroutine_in_c.c:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wiringPiSPI.h>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>

#define LCDADDR             0x27 //IIC LCD address
#define BLEN                1   //1--open backlight,0--close backlight

#define CHAN_CONFIG_SINGLE  8   //setup channel 0 as Single-ended input
#define SPICHANNEL          0   //MCP3008 connect to SPI0
#define ANALOGCHANNEL       0   //Potentiometer connect MCP3008 analog channel 0
#define ANALOGCHANNEL2      1

static int spifd;
static int i2cfd;

void
spiSetup (int spiChannel)
{
  if ((spifd = wiringPiSPISetup (spiChannel, 10000)) < 0)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Can't open the SPI bus: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE) ;
    }
}

int
myAnalogRead(int spiChannel,int channelConfig,int analogChannel)
{
   if (analogChannel<0 || analogChannel>7)
       return -1;
   unsigned char buffer[3] = {1}; // start bit
   buffer[1] = (channelConfig+analogChannel) << 4;
   wiringPiSPIDataRW(spiChannel, buffer, 3);
   return ( (buffer[1] & 3 ) << 8 ) + buffer[2]; // get last 10 bits
}

//write a word to lcd
void
write_word(int data)
{
  int temp = data;
  if ( BLEN == 1 )
    temp |= 0x08;
  else
    temp &= 0xF7;
  wiringPiI2CWrite(i2cfd, temp);
 }

//send command to lcd
void
send_command(int comm)
{
  int buf;
  // Send bit7-4 firstly
  buf = comm & 0xF0;
  buf |= 0x04;            // RS = 0, RW = 0, EN = 1
  write_word(buf);
  delay(2);
  buf &= 0xFB;            // Make EN = 0
  write_word(buf);

  // Send bit3-0 secondly
  buf = (comm & 0x0F) << 4;
  buf |= 0x04;            // RS = 0, RW = 0, EN = 1
  write_word(buf);
  delay(2);
  buf &= 0xFB;            // Make EN = 0
  write_word(buf);
}

//send data to lcd
void
send_data(int data)
{
  int buf;
  // Send bit7-4 firstly
  buf = data & 0xF0;
  buf |= 0x05;            // RS = 1, RW = 0, EN = 1
  write_word(buf);
  delay(2);
  buf &= 0xFB;            // Make EN = 0
  write_word(buf);

  // Send bit3-0 secondly
  buf = (data & 0x0F) << 4;
  buf |= 0x05;            // RS = 1, RW = 0, EN = 1
  write_word(buf);
  delay(2);
  buf &= 0xFB;            // Make EN = 0
  write_word(buf);
}

//initialize the lcd
void
init()
{
  send_command(0x33); // Must initialize to 8-line mode at first
  delay(5);
  send_command(0x32); // Then initialize to 4-line mode
  delay(5);
  send_command(0x28); // 2 Lines & 5*7 dots
  delay(5);
  send_command(0x0C); // Enable display without cursor
  delay(5);
  send_command(0x01); // Clear Screen
  wiringPiI2CWrite(i2cfd, 0x08);
}

//clear screen
void
clear()
{
  send_command(0x01); //clear Screen
}

//Print the message on the lcd
void
write(int x, int y, char data[])
{
  int addr, i;
  int tmp;
  if (x < 0)  x = 0;
  if (x > 15) x = 15;
  if (y < 0)  y = 0;
  if (y > 1)  y = 1;

  // Move cursor
  addr = 0x80 + 0x40 * y + x;
  send_command(addr);

  tmp = strlen(data);
  for (i = 0; i < tmp; i++) {
    send_data(data[i]);
  }
}

void
ler_sensores(float *s1)
{
  int adc;
  int adc2;
  int i;
  float voltage;
  float voltage2;
  char buf[5];
  if (wiringPiSetup() < 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr,"Can't init wiringPi: %s\n",strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  spiSetup(SPICHANNEL);//init spi

  i2cfd = wiringPiI2CSetup(LCDADDR); //init i2c
  init(); //init LCD
  clear(); //clear screen

  for (i = 0; i <25; i++) {
    adc = myAnalogRead(SPICHANNEL,CHAN_CONFIG_SINGLE,ANALOGCHANNEL);
    adc2 = myAnalogRead(SPICHANNEL, CHAN_CONFIG_SINGLE, ANALOGCHANNEL2);
    voltage = adc/1024.*20.0;
    write(0,0,"Ch Linear:");
    sprintf(buf,"%2.2f",voltage);//float change to string
    write(10,0,buf);//print voltage on lcd
    write(15,0,"V");//print unit

    write(0,1,"Ch Logarit:");
    voltage2 = adc2/1024.*20.0;
    sprintf(buf,"%2.2f",voltage2);
    write(11,1, buf);
    write(16,1,"V");
    delay(1000);
  }

  *s1 = voltage;
}
```

---

Thank you in advance to everyone who helps.

Comment: For starters ... You're naming one of your C functions `write`. But, that conflicts with the standard syscall function `write`. Fortran may want to use the syscall version and may have problems because it doesn't know that it is using _your_ function and the arguments are totally different. Better to _rename_ your C function to something like (e.g.) `device_write`. Do this for any other names that conflict.

Comment: Please read about the `VALUE` attribute.  Are you passing by value or reference?

Comment: On the C side we also need the header files wiringPi.h and similar if we want to compile and test this

Comment: The code has an appropriate interface on the Fortran side - the passing of the argument from C to Fortran should be fine

Answer (score 1):

This question probably deserves an answer even if the reason for the problem is the obscure one, identified by Craig Estay.

Gfortran's runtime library, called when using the `print` and `write` statements, contains calls to [`write()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) and having another C function called `write` will cause the gfortran runtime to call a wrong function.

It can easily be tested in a simple program like this:

testwrite.c:

```
#include "stdio.h"
void write(){
  puts("my C write");
}
```

testwrite.f90:

```
print *,"test print"
write(*,*) "test write"
end
```

When using `gfortran testwrite.c testwrite.f90`, the output is:

```
my C write
my C write
my C write
my C write
```

The same output appears when using `icc testwrite.c -c -o c.o` and `ifort c.o testwrite.f90`.